# Sanding & Oiling walnut slab table

Tags: sanding, table-making, tung-oil

I’m making a table out of two thick walnut slabs.
My question is in regard to the order of sanding and oiling.
I’m working on the underside now and put a coat of Tung oil on, thinking it’s good to put this down before attaching the legs.
When doing the top of the table, do I oil, sand repeatedly working my up to a fine course, then oil again? How many coats before/after sanding? I believe I want about 5 or so coats of tung oil.
I’m sure it’s obvious that this is my first technical (to me) wood project.

Thanks a bunch,
Jay

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Did you try a search before you posted? This SE has been going for a number of years so there's already a wealth of information contained in the existing Q&As that might already cover what you want to know. I remember there are at least a handful on actual tung oil as well as "Tung Oil Finish", in case that's what you're using, which is something completely different.

Comment: If after reading the existing Q&As you need more info re-word your Question accordingly, have it focus on only what you need to know and give us more details on exactly what you're working with ("thick walnut slabs" doesn't tell us enough) and what you're sanding with (I'm presuming you're not sanding this purely by hand since almost nobody does this any more, but you need to tell us so we're not guessing).

Comment: BTW if you are using real tung oil and you go ahead with 5 coats you might be looking at a total finishing time in excess of three weeks, with further waiting on top of that before the surface is ready to use. If that sounds reasonable then go ahead, but if that makes you go "What the....?" then I would recommend rethinking the finish for this project. Using almost every competitor, including one of the traditional options that's usually considered slow, you'd be done in under a week.... and your table will look better, and be **far** better protected.

Comment: I'm not sure I'd oil before sanding. Work through the grits and then apply the oil.